# How To Connect Visual Studio Emulator with VScode in Flutter?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

Unable to connect the Android Studio emulator on Debug mode on VScode.
Emulator is On But Not Connected. It ask to connect the device, it starts the emulator but unable to connect on the debugg mode.[image]

Error:emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature. Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

Comment: Post the output of `flutter devices`

Answer (score 0):

There was a race condition in the Dart extension for VS Code that could result in the daemon not detecting your devices:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1919

This has been fixed in the latest version (v3.4.0) so if you update your extension, the problem should go away. If not, please do file a new issue in the Dart-Core repo!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Open your cmd and type 'adb connect yourIPAddressOfTheEmulator' without the quotation mark. You can get the IP address of your emulator under settings/wifi then click the wired wifi to find the Ip address